# How to deep copy string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, deep-copy

I'm new to JavaScript and have a basic question. I have 2 text fields on a server-generated page, and I want to copy the text value of field 1 to field 2, and then set field 1's value to  an empty string. The problem is since JavaScript is doing a shallow copy, field 2's value is set to an empty string as well.

Here is the code:

```
var eleTxtInit = document.getElementById("InputText0");
if (eleTxtInit == null) {
            eleTxtInit = document.getElementsByName("InputText0");
}


var eleTxtControl = document.getElementById("InputText1");
if (eleTxtControl == null) {
            eleTxtControl = document.getElementsByName("InputText1");
}

eleTxtControl.value = eleTxtInit.value;
eleTxtInit.value = "";
```

The result of the above code is that `InputText1` value becomes `""` as well :( ..

What's the solution here ?

Comment: Are you sure that `InputText0` has a value ?

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/NSZUK/ Also, the problem would manifest only if it did a *deep* copy.

Comment: @JBRTRND, yes, `InputText0` does have a string value in it ..

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is:  `eleTxtControl = document.getElementsByName("InputText1");`. `getElementsByName` returns a [Nodelist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList), so you should use

```
eleTxtInit = document.getElementsByName("InputText0")[0];
//and ofcourse
eleTxtControl = document.getElementsByName("InputText1")[0];
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KooiInc/djH5t/)

Comment: Well, the jsfiddle works here. If you're using IE, don't use identical `id's` and `names` for input elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
eleTxtInit = document.getElementsByName("InputText0");
```

triggering will result in the subsequent code failure, since [document.getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName) returns an `HTMLCollection`, not an `Element`. Ditto for `eleTxtControl`.